# Unexpected log2 error when defining S3 "Math" group generics for a new class

Tags: r, class, oop, generics, r-s3

I am trying to use S3 "Math" group generics for a custom class. However I am getting a strange result: `log()` works while `log2` and `log10` produces errors. Below is a minimal example:

```
# simple class with just the new name
lameclass <- function(x) {
  class(x) <- append(class(x), "lame")
  x
}

# It prints something when Math generics methods are used
Math.lame <- function(x, ...) {
  print("I am lame")
  NextMethod()
}

# an object of the class
lamevector <- lameclass(1:10)

> class(lamevector)
[1] "integer" "lame"
```

Now try to call `log`:

```
log(lamevector)
[1] "I am lame"
[1] 0.0000000 0.6931472 1.0986123 1.3862944 1.6094379 1.7917595 1.9459101 2.0794415 2.1972246 2.3025851
```

With base 2:

```
log(lamevector, 2)
[1] "I am lame"
[1] 0.000000 1.000000 1.584963 2.000000 2.321928 2.584963 2.807355 3.000000 3.169925 3.321928
```

All above worked. But now `log2` wrapper:

```
log2(lamevector)
[1] "I am lame"
[1] "I am lame"
Error in log2.default(1:10, 2) :
  2 arguments passed to 'log2' which requires 1
```

Maybe someone can help me with figuring out what is going on here? Did log2 actually went through the generic Math definition 2 times and failed?

Comment: `log2` and `log10` aren't in the S3 Math group generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What appears to be happening is that `NextMethod` is not stripping the `lame` class, so when `log2` calls `log`, it re-dispatches to the `lame` method, which now no longer works, because it's calling `log2` with `base = 2L`, a parameter `log2` doesn't have.

Forcing the dispatch to work correctly doesn't require too much work—just strip and re-add the class. (Aside: Subclasses should be prepended, not appended.)

```r
lameclass <- function(x) {
    class(x) <- c("lame", class(x))    # prepend new class
    x
}

Math.lame <- function(x, ...) {
    print("I am lame")
    class(x) <- class(x)[class(x) != "lame"]    # strip lame class
    lameclass(NextMethod())    # re-add lame class to result
}

lamevector <- lameclass(1:5)

log(lamevector)
#> [1] "I am lame"
#> [1] 0.0000000 0.6931472 1.0986123 1.3862944 1.6094379
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "lame"    "numeric"
log(lamevector, 2)
#> [1] "I am lame"
#> [1] 0.000000 1.000000 1.584963 2.000000 2.321928
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "lame"    "numeric"
log2(lamevector)
#> [1] "I am lame"
#> [1] 0.000000 1.000000 1.584963 2.000000 2.321928
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "lame"    "numeric"
```

I'm not precisely sure *why* it's dispatching like that. Group generics are a little weird, and dispatch on `oldClass` instead of `class`, which may or may not be part of the issue. It may just be a bug. The idiom of stripping and re-adding the class is used in other `Math` methods, possibly for this reason:

```r
MASS:::Math.fractions
#> function (x, ...) 
#> {
#>     x <- unclass(x)
#>     fractions(NextMethod())
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x7ff8782a1558>
#> <environment: namespace:MASS>
```

Comment: Thanks. Great work around with stripping and re-adding the class and a nice example from MASS. +1 and accepted. One last question thou - do you think it makes sense to strip and re-add class for other group generics as well (just in case) ? I am a bit paranoid now about there being other functions with the same issue as log2.

Comment: Probably, yes; MASS does. `units:::Math.units` takes a more function-specific approach, which seems much harder to write. Of the other group generics, `Ops` may require more attention yet, as it uses double dispatch. Whatever approach you use, test rigorously.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment `log2` ,`log10` aren't in the `S3 Math` generic. In fact, `exp`, `expm1`, `log`, `log10`, `log2` and `log1p` are **S4** generic and are members of the Math group generic.

One way to implement what do you want to do is to define you class as **S4** class.

```
setClass("lame4", slots = c(x = "numeric"))
```

And define the method `Math` group generic :

```
setMethod("Math","lame4",function(x) {
                x@x <- callGeneric(x@x)
                x
          }) 
## pretty print 
setMethod("show", "lame4",function(object)print(object@x))
```

Now let's test it :

```
l1 <- new("lame4",x=1:10)
```

Then:

```
log2(l1)
 [1] 0.000000 1.000000 1.584963 2.000000 2.321928 2.584963 2.807355 3.000000 3.169925 3.321928
> log10(l1)
 [1] 0.0000000 0.3010300 0.4771213 0.6020600 0.6989700 0.7781513 0.8450980 0.9030900 0.9542425
[10] 1.0000000
```

This of course not a direct answer to your question, but explains why your implementation does not work. Here I think that using `S4` paradigm is a good idea because you will have  stronger typing which is very helpful with mathematics. S4 methods works fine with R.C/Rcpp interface also. But if you are new to it there is a certain learning curve ( depends in your development background)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response @agstudy . And thanks for the S4 suggestion, but I have to point out - I am not looking for that at all. The actual task I had actually went by OK without using Math group generics for S3 (as both log and log2 preserved the class of my object). The question is more of a surprise that Math.generics breaks log2. If log2 wasn't covered by Math I would expect it to not be affected by it, not break. And I am wondering is this intentional or some sort of bug in R base.

Comment: But +1 because I think this might be useful for people with similar questions in the future (i.e. knowing they can turn to S4). However I still think this doesn't really explain the behaviour of `log2` - lot's of other functions are not included under Math generics, but they don't break once Math generics is defined. So something is still missing I feel.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičiuscan you add in your question the generics from Math that does not broke your S3 class implementation?  This will clarify the example.

Comment: For my case I had a custom class defined and all I wanted from generics was they they preserved my class. Turned out it worked WITHOUT actually defining Math group generics at all :) So there was no "working implementation" as such...

Comment: Note that the S4 generic for **log** has a signature with only one argument, SO i don't think that there is a bug here it is just an implementation choice.

Comment: The way I am seeing it is like this: there is S3 system for OOP. It has group generics. I implement one group generics and it breaks some functions (that are not even in that generics category). And as far as I see there is no way to implement Math generics without breaking those functions. Wouldn't that be considered a bug? It might be intentional, but in that case a list of all the functions that will be broken after implementing Math. should be available somewhere.